# How can I avoid printing the separator when elements are empty in the join()?

Tags: php, arrays, join

Here is my code:-

```
echo join(',', ['','']);
```

As you know, it [prints just a comma](https://3v4l.org/QbNSh). I want to avoid that. Because elements are empty and the only comma doesn't make any sense. Also the comma should be deleted in [this](https://3v4l.org/8XHnX):

```
echo join(',', ['sth','']);
// the expected result: sth
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove empty items of the array. You can do that simply by using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function. So try this:

```
echo join(',', array_filter(['sth','']));
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/fZIjO)